# Determining a child object from a token and initializing it

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

So I have an abstract parent class with 6 child classes extending it. I have a fileRead(String) method that reads data from a file. The first line of the file has a category ID (*FOODTYPE*_CATID) and a name, separated by the '|' (pipe) character, which is my delimiter to use in String Tokenizer. I have 6 if statements checking the token and  initializing the appropriate object. However, this is where I run into problems, I want to use the object later on in the method but can't because

- A) since it's in the if() statements the compiler thinks the might
  not have been initialized and
- B) I can't initialize it before the if statements because it's
  abstract. I also only want to use this single object, I do not want
  to initialize 6 different objects and have 50 different if statements
  in a single method.

So my question is, how do I only use one object for this type of problem? Here is some code for reference:

```
    Public abstract class Recipe { methods }
    Public class Soup extends Recipe { methods } //There are 5 other classes like this
    Public class Controller 
    {
         doSomething() { logic } 
         doThis() { logic };
         readFile(String str)
         {
               recipeFile.open( "recipes.dat");
               if ( recipeFile.exists() )
               {
                     // read first line from the recipe file
                     recipeLine = recipeFile.readLine();
                     String Tokenizer token; 

                     while ( recipeLine != null)
                     {
                          token = new String Tokenizer(recipeLine, "|");
                          Recipe recipe;

                          if(token.hasMoreTokens())
                          {
                               if(token.equals(SOUP_CATID))
                               {
                                    recipe = new Soup();
                                    recipe.setName(token.toString());
                               }
                               ...more if statements checking other catId's
                          }
                          Ingredients i = new Ingredient();
                          recipeFile.open( "ingredients.dat");
                          while(logic)
                          {
                                //This will not work because recipe
                                //still hasn't been initialized before the if
                                //statements
                                recipe.addIngredient(i);
                          }
                     }
                }
           }
      }
```

*EDIT* Solved - All I had to do was initialize recipe to null before the if statements. 
          Recipe recipe = null;
Didn't produce any errors and the code/logic works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't think your `recipe` instance won't be initialized before you get to the ingredient processing logic, but in any case I would recommend reading up on [Factory patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: I actually just figured it out. It's not that I didn't know that recipe would be initialized, the compiler kept complaining that recipe might not have been initialized. Anyways, all I had to do was initialize recipe to null before the if statements. Didn't produce any errors. Thanks for the input too